# Tag merge suggestion: [equipment] and [exercise-equipment]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

As the title says, both [equipment](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) and [exercise-equipment](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercise-equipment) refer to devices that allows the execution of, or assists with specific exercises. I don't see the need for both these tags to coexist - I'd say all equipment questions here should be about *exercise* equipments so there shouldn't be a need to specify that in the tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve made [equipment](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) a synonym of [exercise-equipment](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercise-equipment).

Be aware, there is already UI in place to suggest tag synonyms here: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

If you find more good candidates, just make a suggestion there and ping me in chat and I can review them.

Comment: oh thanks, I was not aware of that UI

Comment: Actually, I can't make any suggestion, I don't have enough rep here...

Comment: @Luciano Oh, then just ping me in [chat].